# JavaFX - How to store a created control in an FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I wasn't sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284904/save-javafx-scene-into-fxml-file) is the same as my question, but I decided to ask anyway. If it is, I apologize and will delete this if needed.

My question is, if I let a user create a new field and then in my code, that field is generated and shown on the scene, once the user closes the application and re-opens it, the field will be gone.

Is there a way to save that field into the `main.fxml` file or do I have to save the data of the field in a database and then re-create it dynamically every time the user re-opens the application? If it's the latter, how does SceneBuilder do it?

Comment: "if I let a user create a new field and then in my code, that field is generated and shown on the scene, once the user closes the application and re-opens it, the field will be gone".  You may wish to edit the question to add an [mcve] for this, so it is easier to understand and replicate exactly what you are doing.

Comment: "Is there a way to save that field into the main.fxml file or do I have to save the data of the field".  Saving "a created control" and saving data in a field are pretty different things.  Are you trying to one or the other or both?  Does the data in the field change dynamically based on user inputs, database values or some other means, or is it just some static constant?

Comment: Scene Builder is a development tool specifically designed to ease the creation of FXML files. It "simply" lets you design the scene graph visually and then it saves the structure in an FXML file. You then take the FXML file, add it to your application's resources, and finally load/parse it at runtime via an `FXMLLoader`. Once the FXML file is embedded in your application is must be treated as read-only, same as all resources. In other words, unless you're creating another [WYSIWYG editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) then "_how does Scene Builder do it_" is probably not relevant.

Comment: That said, not all views can be fully implemented in an FXML file. If your view is as dynamic as you say then some of it will need to be created on-the-fly, probably in the controller. Now, adding a field to the UI shouldn't happen in a vacuum; your application should have some sort of model (see MVC, MVVM, etc.) where updates to it cause the view to add a field. To put it another way, the field should be "linked" to something. You can then save the _model_ and when you re-run the application you load the model and create the view based on its state.

Comment: Well a fxml file is a xml file (assuming you don't load it from other sources such as via network or from a jar entry. Theoretically you could overwrite this file with a new structure, but that's about the most complicated (and least flexible) way you could go about this. The db approach (whatever you consider a db in this case; this may not be a sql db, just e.g. a csv file or an even simpler text file) would be much simplert to implement...

Comment: @jewelsea I didn't think a minimal reproducible example was needed because I'm not asking for actual coding examples but more like what logic I should use. As for what I mean by "data", I mean the properties you have in the side bar of the SceneBuilder and not the input of the field.

Comment: @Slaw I'm not really familiar with MVC/MVVM. I read some definitions and checked  the wiki example of [mvvmFX implementation](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/Getting-Started-HelloWorld-%28english%29) but even after doing so, I'm not sure why I would need such a thing. From the little I understood about MVVM, you seem to need to already know what fields will need to be and do and if you're doing things dynamically, you don't really know what those will be. (Not sure if I'm explaining myself well.)

Comment: @fabian Yeah I was thinking of maybe using a `Map<String, String>()`. In the first string I put he `fx:id` (when a button is clicked, a prompt would ask the user for what that `fx:id` should be) and the second string would be the input of the field. Then when the application is loaded, create the new fields according to the `Map`.

Comment: Your `Map<String, String>` would be the model (or possibly the view-model, depending on the architecture). You dynamically create the fields based on the state of said model. When your user adds a field the model is updated. You then save the state of the model, not the view. The view is simply a _visual representation_ of the model and should not be concerned with the business logic of the application nor how the model is persisted. Similarly, the model should not be concerned with how or when it's displayed.

Comment: Also, if you're attempting to create an application similar to Scene Builder then you can always look at Scene Builder's [source code](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder) for research. Note that the project is not exactly trivial.

Comment: @Slaw Thank for the `Map` explanation. Now things make more sense. And no, I'm not making an application similar to SceneBuilder, that is way out of my league. If you want, copy/paste your comments into a solution and I'll mark it as the correct one because this example pretty much answered my question in a way that I can understand it.